# Keyboard conf at `/etc/profile` does not work

Tags: x11, profile, setxkbmap

This is a script that I can source or run to setup my keyboard layout:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Testing to only apply the layout to Kinesis keyboard.
# Get Device ID with: `xinput -list | grep -i key
debug_out=/tmp/layout_kinesis.log

echo "layout_kinesis start" >> $debug_out 2>&1
echo $SHELL >> $debug_out 2>&1
date >> $debug_out 2>&1
whoami >> $debug_out 2>&1
kinesis_device_id=$(xinput --list | grep "05f3:0007[[:blank:]]*id=" | sed -n "s/^.*id=\(\S*\).*/\1/p") >> $debug_out 2>&1
echo "layout_kinesis id $kinesis_device_id" >> $debug_out 2>&1
if [ ! -z "$kinesis_device_id" ] ; then
    echo "layout_kinesis on display $DISPLAY" >> $debug_out 2>&1
    xkbcomp -i $kinesis_device_id /home/gauthier/kinesis/kinesis_swe_us.conf $DISPLAY >> $debug_out 2>&1
fi
echo "layout_kinesis id done" >> $debug_out 2>&1
```

Sorry for the redirection craze, I got paranoid.

This works when I run or source it while already logged in.

Now I want to set it up for anyone logging in, as long as the keyboard is connected. I copied the script to `/etc/profile.d/layout_kinesis.sh`. It has these permissions: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root` .

The layout is not loaded.

The debug output file seems reasonable (`stderr` redirection required for `xkbcomp`: a pop-up "Do you want to proceed?" appears otherwise), shell is `/bin/bash`, user is my user, the `id` (9) and `DISPLAY` (`:0`) seem correct, I get a bunch of warnings from `xkbcomp` but they're as usual.

Sourcing `/etc/profile.d/layout_kinesis.sh` manually from a terminal emulator after login makes it work, so why doesn't it in the first place? It seems to source correctly, but the effects are not there. Could some other start file overwrite this setting?

---

Things I've looked into:

- There is no other mention of `xkbcomp` or `setxkbmap` in `/etc/profile.d/`.
- nothing related in `~/.profile`, no `~/.bash_profile` nor `~/.bash_login`

This is on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: How do you start the X session? With `startx`, or does a display manager do it? I don't think you should put it in `.profile` because that is only for login shells. Rather you should put it in the file that is executed when X starts, typically `.xinitrc` (but will depend on your system).

Comment: There's an entry `/usr/share/xsessions/xmonad.desktop`, it executes `xmonad-session`, which is in `/usr/bin/`. This is turn sources `.xmonad/xmonad-session-rc`, which is in my `$HOME`, then executes `xmonad`. I want the script to run (well, it does, but to have effect) for all users, and for all WM that I might want to use.

Comment: If you use `startx`, `.xinitrc` would suffice. If a display manager does it, then I don't know.

Comment: Do you mean `~/.xinitrc`? Then it's not for every user.